# Is it possible to do a firmware update using the Azure IoT Hub and Blob storage?

Tags: c, download, binaryfiles, azure-iot-hub, firmware

I have the azure IoT client running on an STM32H7 with Keil RTX 5 as its operating system. What I want to do is download a binary file from Azure (firmware) and update the firmware on my device (STM32H7).

What I have done:

I have uploaded a binary file to Azure blob storage. 
I have got the sample "iothub_client_device_twin_and_methods_sample.c" example working and running correctly (It connects to the Azure IoT hub with no issues)

I want to go about my firmware update by downloading this binary file and then writing it to a storage area on my device, but I think I have the latter part covered.

From my current research, I believe the correct approach to this is to somehow create a cloud to device message containing the binary file.

My question is, based on the above:

What is the correct way to download a binary file from blob storage using the C sdk to my embedded device?

PS: I have seen there is an example for a firmware update using the raspberry pi but I was not able to understand it and modify it for my purpose.

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: my firmware update will be firmware over the air, hence the need for a way to download it from Azure

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at the way the ESP-IDF implements FOTA:

[ESP32 OTA via HTTPS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ck55tY7mm1c)

[ESPRESSIG - Over The Air Updates](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/api-reference/system/ota.html)

You can as well take a look at the following AN from NXP:
[Firmware Update Using Secondary Bootloader](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN12327.pdf)

To download the firmware, you can use raw tcp/ip, http(s), ftp, etc...

If you type "arm bootloader" in google, you will get a lot of useful content:

[Why every Cortex-M developer should consider using a bootloader](http://blog.atollic.com/why-every-cortex-m-developer-should-consider-using-a-bootloader)

[From Zero to main(): How to Write a Bootloader from Scratch](https://interrupt.memfault.com/blog/how-to-write-a-bootloader-from-scratch)

Answer (score 0):

In answer to my own question:

I found that the C sdk does support uploading files to blob storage but not downloading then. The best approach to downloading them I found was to install a HTTP library and request to download the file from Azure storage. I also found that there seems to be no way of using the C SDK to do a firmware over the air update as I had first imagined.